# How to reference different kinds of lines and markers?

Tags: phrase-request

Consider the below figure ( The Figure is an example that I drew it)

[image]

Questions:

I know the the lines 1 and 2 can be referenced as "solid line" and "dashed line", respectively.

However, the question is **how should I reference the the line number 3** ? I came up with two phrases,"dashed and doted line", "doted and dashed line". Are these concocted phrases correct ? If no, any suggestion would be appreciated. In general, is there any source that I can use to learn to how reference such a things ?

The next question is: **when the lines are accompanied with markers, How these Markers can be referenced** ? I came up with "empty" and "filled" for the examples 4 and 5, respectively. Are these phrases OK? If no, may I know your comments ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For compact descriptive terms like this, you can be fairly flexible, especially if the reader can see the symbols that you are describing.

If you want to find a nice term, or a widely used one, you can google each of the options you are considering: google may even come up with something more suitable. Those used by the big statistical packages are likely to be the most appropriate.

Here are some of the possibilities I found for line 3:  dash-dot (Matlab, Octave), dot-dashed (Wolfram), dot-and-dash (Merriam-Webster).

For lines 4 and 5, you could use the black square/white square (unicode), empty box/filled box (nobody famous), solid square/empty square (Matlab), empty square/filled square (Quattro pro).

Answer (score 0):

I think #3 is "Dashed Line with Dots"

Comment: And What about the Markers ?